# How to use multiple subscriber call in a component without overriding the data of all the subscriber calls

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, rxjs6

I am using 3 API services in different tabs of mat-tab, but when I am switching between tabs, I am getting the data combined from all the 3 APIs.

I have defined three functions in a component in which I am calling different APIs in all the different functions and calling the 3 functions in the ngOninit(). When printing the fetched data into the console, I am getting data appended to one another.

For instance, if function 1, has 20 records, function 2 has 3, and function 3 has also 3.

So, if function 1 is executed first, then 20 records will be logged, after that if function 2 is executed, then 20+3=23 records will be logged(whereas here only 3 shall be logged), and finally when function 3 is executed, it returns, 23+3=26 records(here also it should be only 3).

Tried to unsubscribe the function after the value is fetched in a particular function. Was not able to do it.

```
constructor(private _server: ServerService) {}
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.f1();
  this.f2()
}

getf1(): void {
  this._server.getf1count()
       .subscribe(exeJened => {
      this.exeJened = exeJened
      console.log('exe',this.exeJened)
     })
}
getf2(): void 
{
  this._server.getf2count()
       .subscribe(queJened => {
      this.queJened = queJened
    console.log('que',this.queJened) }

     })
}
```

Result of exe: array of 20 records
Result of que: array of 23 records
whereas, exe has 20 and que has 3 records.
Not able to upload screenshot.

Code for serverservice:

```
 constructor(private _http: HttpClient){}
getf1count():Observable<any>
  {
  return this._http.get(this.executed_URL)
  .pipe(
        map(exeresult=>exeresult['serverserials']),
        retry(4),
        catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }
  getf2count():Observable<any>
  {
  return this._http.get(this.queued_URL)
  .pipe(
        map(queresult=>queresult['serverserials']),
        retry(4),
        catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: please post code and screenshot

Comment: Can you show the code of the service ServerService?

Comment: @powkachu, i have added the code for serverservice. please check

Comment: @RishabPathak If you are using `HttpClient` you can omit `.map` , you will directly get response in `subscribe`

Comment: thanks @pardeepJain for letting me know that. :)